# Using a ToggleButton in a widget?

Tags: android, widget, togglebutton

I am building a widget that currently works with buttons. I want to use ToggleButtons instead, so I change the main.xml to reflect that. Then I run the widget on my droid x and it say "Porblem loading widget." I see no errors.

So my question is, can I use ToggleButtons in a widget?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, but `ToggleButton` is not an available widget for use in app widgets. You may be able to achieve a similar effect by changing the icon on the face of an `ImageButton`.

Comment: How to figure out from the documentation that ToggleButtons aren't available in Widgets? I didn't find any hint about this...

Comment: @Bob: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout